# Conditions for which groups of states of markov chain still represent a markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider a 3x3 Markov chain matrix for 3 different states $j=1,2,3$.

$$ W= \left(\begin{matrix}W_{11}&W_{12}&W_{13}\\W_{21}&W_{22}&W_{23}\\W_{31}&W_{32}&W_{33}\end{matrix}\right) $$

If I define two states $I,II$ as

- $I$ is $1$
- $II$ is obtained joining $2$ and $3$

What are the conditions on the matrix elements $W_{ij}$ under which $I$ and $II$ are the states of a new **Markov** chain?

---

I think that the conditions are

- $W_{21}=W_{31}$
- $W_{22}=W_{33}$ and $W_{23}=W_{32}$

Otherwise the probabilities $W_{II,I}$ and $W_{II,II}$ would not be defined.

---

But I would like to have an explanation on how to derive those conditions from the definition of Markov chain, i.e. the transition probability must not depend on past states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely you need to have $W_{21}=W_{31}$, so as to make sure that the probability for the transition from state II to state I doesn't depend on whether state II was an instance of state $2$ or an instance of state $3$.

But as I see it, that's all you need.

Ler $a=W_{11}$, and let $b=W_{21}=W_{31}$.

Then the Markov chain for the new states has transition matrix
$$
\pmatrix
{
a & 1-a \cr
b & 1-b
}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I still don't see why the second condition ($W_{22}=W_{33}$ and $W_{23}=W_{32}$) is not necessary.  For the same reason that you mentioned, considering the probability from state II to state II, to make sure it does not depend on wheter state II was an istance of 2 or of 3, then (according to me) it should be  $W_{22}=W_{33}$ and $W_{23}=W_{32}$ since 

$$P(II \to II)=P(2 \to 2 \,\,\, or \,\,\, 3 \to 3)+P(2 \to 3 \,\,\, or \,\,\, 3 \to 2)$$

Am I missing something?

Comment: Assuming $W_{21}=W_{31}=b$, it follows that from either state $2$ or state $3$ the probability of going to state $2$ or state $3$ is $1-b$, so for the transition from state II to state II it doesn't matter if the source state ii is an instance of state $2$ or state $3$.